# Mongoosastic - indexing ObjectId into elastic search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I would like to index my mongoDB objectID when indexing to Elastic Search

Like this :

```
_id : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, es_indexed:true},
parentItem : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, Ref:'SystemItem', es_indexed:true }
```

This produce `undefined` when mongoosastic is importing my db into elastic search

There is a way to do this? Or should I go other way?

Comment: Even I tried inserting _id to elastic search. But mongoosastic is failing to do that. But you can find other ways to do it. Like autoIncrement. Which I followed.

Comment: The _id doesn't have to be specified in your model definition. Mongoose will automatically add one in every document, unless you set _id: false.
Mongoosastic use the same mongodb IDs